# Unable to get second column using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file that contains three columns separated by four spaces

```
1234    567    q
1902    190    r
```

I'm trying to get the second column by searching for the first column string

```
i=`grep $str $file | awk -F "[    ]" '{print $2 }'`
j=`grep $str $file | awk -F "[    ]" '{print $3 }'` 
echo second_col=$i
echo third_col=$j
```

I modified the file and used tab and comma as separators but I'm still unable to print the second or third column values for a particular string.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Huh? If you want column 2 and 3 of a line starting with `1902`, just do `awk '/^1902/{print $2,$3}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get the second column by searching for the first column string

If you don't have spaces in your columns then you can just use `awk` for this:

```
awk -v str="$str" '$1 ~ str { print $2 }' "$file"
```

`awk` automatically splits fields on whitespaces.

In case you have spaces in your column value then use:

```
awk -F ' {4}' -v str="$str" '$1 ~ str { print $2 }' "$file"
```

`' {4}'` is a regex to make 4 spaces a input field separator.

**Reference:** [Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf)

Comment: `-F' {4}'` is superfluous. `awk` will split fields by *runs of spaces* by default.

Comment: I tried it again and it worked. There was an issue with the file contents.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a broken `awk` try this solution with `sed`

```
sed -nE 's/^1234\s+(\S+).*/\1/p'
```

find the pattern at the beginning of the line and print the next non-space field.  If your fields include spaces this approach is not going to work.